# Implementing a basic Twitter/Facebook @mention system

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database, pdo

I'm trying to create a basic @mention system for a microblogging application that I am creating (it's a project for me to learn PDO).

I read a few other [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5182301/2332251) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456339/2332251) and [threads](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=266258),but I still can't understand what everyone is saying.

What I have at the moment is a database structure, something like this:

```
**mentions:** <br>
mention_id (primary key auto increment) <br> 
post_id (id from the posts table) <br> 
user_id (id of the user who is mentioned) <br>
unread (either 0 or 1 depending on whether the post has been viewed by the user mentioned)

**posts:** <br>
post_id (primary key auto increment) <br> 
user_id (id of the user who posted) <br> 
post_content (the post contents)<br> 
stamp (the post time stamp)
```

The way I think it has to work based on previous posts is this - we add the post to the database and then run a function over it to grab the post_id THEN we run a regex statement over it and pull out all the references to @something, then we chop off the @ symbol and run it through a function to check if there is a user by that name. If there is a user by that name we insert their user_id, the post_id and a 1 into the unread column into the mentions table of the database so that later we can check if our currently logged in user has any unread mentions and display those. I understand this method may not scale well, but I'm not looking at holding millions of users I just want a simple solution.

So... what I'm looking for is for someone to take a look at what I have so far and let me know how I can make it work and/or suggest a better/more simple approach.

The end result I want is for a user to be able to @mention another user and to be able to display it as an 'unread' mention until the mentioned user views their notifications (a list of mentions etc e.g. like Facebook).

What I have thus far is this:

```
$post_content = 'Yo @jack, what up? I have a new email, jack@bob.com'; 
// to be later replaced with $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

// right here would be a function add_post that
// inserts the post_content, user_id and time stamp into the database

function select_post($post_content){
    $sql = "SELECT 
              post_id
            FROM posts
            WHERE post_content = $post_content
          "; 
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
}

function valid_username($mentionedUser){
    $sql = "SELECT 
              username
            FROM users
            WHERE username = $mentionedUser
          "; 
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
}

function insert_mention($post_id, $mentionedUser){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 
            mentions (post_id, user_id, unread)
            VALUES (:post_id, :user_id, 1) // 1 means unread
            ";
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);                                      
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $mentionedUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
    $stmt->execute();
}

add_post($userid, $post_content);
$post_id = select_post($post_content);

if (preg_match("/\B@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/i", $post_content)) {

    preg_match_all("/\B@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/i", $post_content, $mentions);
    $mentions = array_map(function($str){ return substr($str, 1); }, $mentions[0]);
    foreach($mentions as $mentionedUser){
        if(!valid_username($mentionedUser)){ continue; }
        insert_mention($post_id, $mentionedUser);   
    }
```

Am I even anywhere on the right track? How can I make this work? Please, the more detail in your answer, the better, I'm interested in what syntax you would use not just a general overview.

Comment: Start from [learning PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you, I took a look and also looked at a few of the links there. Still doesn't give me much clarity. Is my logic completely off? How would you approach it in a simple beginner-like way?

Comment: "_So... what I'm looking for is for someone to take a look at what I have so far and let me know how I can make it work and/or suggest a better/more simple approach._" That's pretty open-ended. For best results, identify a particular problem in your current approach and trim your question to address just that part. Repeat with future questions as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't select post by post content to get post id! You must do the other way around! (select content from post ID)
What you must do:

```
Get post content from any source (hardcoded, user input)
Insert it in database.
post-id = Get last inserted id
get all mentions
foreach mention,  then 
     get the mentionned user
     insert it in database
Done
```

I'll not write it for you but I recommend you to check individualy:
Inserting post
extracting mentions (print_r will show you what $mentions contains, so use it for debugging) 
Inserting mention reference.

I think there is a problem with how you use the contents of the $mentions variable.

Also valid_username doesn't return a boolean, but you are using like it was (if(!...)) so maybe your logic is bad here (at least function name/content/usage)

Ho and, for every function you use, check http://php.net/docs.php Trust me it'll help you to make more logic code by knowing the logic behind what you use.

Comment: Thanks Atrekaur, I'll step back and take your approach. :)